# Server 2012 - Unable to install Windows Updates

Tags: updates, windows-server-2012, dism, sfc

We are having issues installing windows updates(we use Ivanti to install updates) on Server 2012.  SharePoint 2013 is installed on this server.  An example is KB4540726 won't install.  Manually installing the updates show the updates installing (a few seconds), then a restart is required message appears but the KB's don't appear in Installed Updates after a restart.

I ran dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth, sfc /scannow and same behavior.

Note: No issues installing SharePoint updates.

Are there other logs I can check?  I don't see errors in Application or System Logs under Event Viewer.

How can I get these updates installed?

---

Update - log file information:

2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent   ** START **  Agent: Installing updates [CallerId = wusa]
2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent   *********
2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent     * Updates to install = 1
2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent     *   Title = Security Update for Windows (KB4532920)
2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent     *   UpdateId = {ACED0E5A-FFC9-4B20-A741-1221F403C28E}.501
2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent     *     Bundles 1 updates:
2020-06-06  16:06:17:450     992    3b08    Agent     *       {5BCC7973-7CA2-40D2-8327-DF1B12B47F34}.501
2020-06-06  16:06:17:465     992    3b08    Handler Attempting to create remote handler process as PMINSCO\username in session 3
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512     992    3b08    DnldMgr Preparing update for install, updateId = {5BCC7973-7CA2-40D2-8327-DF1B12B47F34}.501.
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512    16416   b28 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.8.9200.22695, tz: -0400)  ===========
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512    16416   b28 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512    16416   b28 Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wuaueng.dll
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512    16416   b28 Handler :::::::::::::
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512    16416   b28 Handler :: START ::  Handler: CBS Install
2020-06-06  16:06:17:512    16416   b28 Handler :::::::::
2020-06-06  16:06:17:528    16416   b28 Handler Starting install of CBS update 5BCC7973-7CA2-40D2-8327-DF1B12B47F34
2020-06-06  16:06:17:528    16416   b28 Handler CBS session identity: 30817341_4030603473
2020-06-06  16:06:17:528    16416   b28 Handler CBS package identity: Package_for_KB4532920~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.1.4
2020-06-06  16:06:17:528    16416   b28 Handler Installing self-contained with source=C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\755aaabd3d49df852a129eced49f8171\Windows8-RT-KB4532920-x64.cab, workingdir=C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\755aaabd3d49df852a129eced49f8171\inst
2020-06-06  16:06:22:146    16416   b28 Handler Requesting post-reboot reporting for package Package_for_KB4532920~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.1.4.
2020-06-06  16:06:22:161    16416   b28 Handler Completed install of CBS update with type=3, requiresReboot=1, installerError=0, hr=0x0

Comment: A log file is generated when an update fails to install.  What errors are being logged?

Comment: Ivanti shows error 3010 which means a restart is required to complete install.  I have restarted multiple times.

dism log shows total detected corruption = 0.

cbs log does not show an install error.

Not seeing errors related to the updates that won't install in windowsupdate.log

Comment: [Do you have any of the previous updates installed?](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=e8c30419-04d7-42eb-b765-8b2789b84401)

Comment: KB4512939 and KB3173426 are installed.

Comment: Try installing `KB4532920`, `KB4532920` replaced `KB4512939` when it was released in December 2019.  Provide any relevant logs from that attempt.

Comment: I manually installed KB4532920, received message that it installed and to restart.  After a restart KB4532920 is not installed. Is there any way to upload the log file?

Comment: We don't want the entire log file only the relevant information.  There is no way to upload a file here at Super User.

Comment: @C1TonyB: have you tried WSUS Offline instead? In Server, a corrupted WU store is rare, but it happens, and it's a pain in the rear to get it back to work properly, much more so than in Windows 10.

Comment: 2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent ** START **  Agent: Installing updates [CallerId = wusa]
2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent *********
2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent   * Updates to install = 1
2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent   *   Title = Security Update for Windows (KB4532920)
2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent   *   UpdateId = {ACED0E5A-FFC9-4B20-A741-1221F403C28E}.501
2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent   *     Bundles 1 updates:
2020-06-06 16:06:17:450  992 3b08 Agent   *       {5BCC7973-7CA2-40D2-8327-DF1B12B47F34}.501

Comment: 2020-06-06 16:06:17:465  992 3b08 Handler Attempting to create remote handler process as PMINSCO\username in session 3
2020-06-06 16:06:17:512  992 3b08 DnldMgr Preparing update for install, updateId = {5BCC7973-7CA2-40D2-8327-DF1B12B47F34}.501.
2020-06-06 16:06:17:512 16416 b28 Misc ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.8.9200.22695, tz: -0400)  ===========
2020-06-06 16:06:17:512 16416 b28 Misc   = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
2020-06-06 16:06:17:512 16416 b28 Misc   = Module: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wuaueng.dll

Comment: 2020-06-06 16:06:17:512 16416 b28 Handler :::::::::::::
2020-06-06 16:06:17:512 16416 b28 Handler :: START ::  Handler: CBS Install
2020-06-06 16:06:17:512 16416 b28 Handler :::::::::
2020-06-06 16:06:17:528 16416 b28 Handler Starting install of CBS update 5BCC7973-7CA2-40D2-8327-DF1B12B47F34
2020-06-06 16:06:17:528 16416 b28 Handler CBS session identity: 30817341_4030603473
2020-06-06 16:06:17:528 16416 b28 Handler CBS package identity: Package_for_KB4532920~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.1.4

Comment: 2020-06-06 16:06:17:528 16416 b28 Handler Installing self-contained with source=C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\755aaabd3d49df852a129eced49f8171\Windows8-RT-KB4532920-x64.cab, workingdir=C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\755aaabd3d49df852a129eced49f8171\inst
2020-06-06 16:06:22:146 16416 b28 Handler Requesting post-reboot reporting for package Package_for_KB4532920~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.2.1.4.

Comment: 2020-06-06 16:06:22:161 16416 b28 Handler Completed install of CBS update with type=3, requiresReboot=1, installerError=0, hr=0x0
2020-06-06 16:06:22:177 16416 b28 Handler :::::::::
2020-06-06 16:06:22:177 16416 b28 Handler ::  END  ::  Handler: CBS Install

Comment: @Didier: I have not tried WSUS Offline.

Comment: I think you should, because it would trigger a complete reset of your WU store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what fixed my issue:

++no Driver operation pending found on the machine

++checked the Trusted installer service, was set to manual

++set the TI service to automatic and re-start the service

++Restart the machine, updates installed